# Collect per-TCP connection statistics on Linux without promiscuous mode (e.g. without tcpdump)

Tags: tcp, linux

Linux keeps per-interface statistics, ifconfig reports them just fine.

But does Linux keep per-TCP connection statistics, specifically, how many rx/tx bytes this session?  If it does, I sure can't find them.

Can you?

Answer (score 4):

A [Google search for IPtraf](https://www.google.com/search?q=iptraf) will point you in the right direction and includes articles on topics such as pairing IPtraf with RDDtool for graphing connections over time.

Comment: +1, same thing I was going to suggest.